# Promise Returning play.libs.F$Promise@65722df2 instead of String Value

Tags: java, playframework, promise, future

So I'm just experimenting in Play and I wanted to see if I could use a promise function to return a String.

In this example I am trying to grab a UserFirstName and instead get the value of play.libs.F$Promise@65722df2.

```
  public static String retrieveUserFirstName(String ch, Service Service,
                                     SessionContext SessionContext, String aN) {

      return Service.getInformation(UteContextArgs.getProcessingContext(),
              SessionContext, aN, ch)
              .filter(info -> info instanceof Information)
              .filter(info -> Constants.ch.equalsIgnoreCase(ch))
              .map(info -> {
                  Information information = (Information) info;
                  return information.getFirstName();
              }).toString();
  }


  public void trySomething (){

      String userFirstName = retrieveUserFirstName(ch, Service,
                                     SessionContext, aN);

      logger.info (context, "here is the userfirstname={}", userFirstName);

  }

  public F.Promise<Information> getInformation(...) {
  ...
  }
```

Upon runtime if I try to manipulate the variable as a string in anyway I get "null pointer exception".

logs show:

```
  here is the userfirstname=play.libs.F$Promise@ca3706e
```

Comment: Have you implemented a `toString` method in the `Promise` or `Information` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently getting the string representation of the `Promise` itself, not its `String` result.

You need to [`get`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#get(long)) the result of the Promise.

Comment: thank you for the response, i see that get requires a "user defined timeout in milliseconds", what is the best practice in defining this timeout?

Comment: Best practice is to understand how long you expect it to take, how long you are willing to wait, how often you are prepared for it to timeout etc. These are all things which are dependent on your particular application.